# change unity themes on command line

Tags: command-line, unity, themes, tweak

I want my Ubuntu 16.04 to automatically switch between bright and dark themes on a daily basis. Up to now I do it manually through the **Unity Tweak Tool**.

How can I change the unity theme on the command line?

Answer (score 3):

In order to switch to Ubuntu's default Ambiance experience, execute these commands:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/interface/gtk-theme '"Ambiance"'
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/interface/icon-theme '"ubuntu-mono-dark"'
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/interface/cursor-theme '"DMZ-White"'
```

To switch to a different theme, adjust the value(s) accordingly.

Note that the values are case sensitive, and do not necessarily match the ones you see in Unity Tweak Tool. This tool seems to auto-capitalize the first letter and convert the rest to lowercase. Try a couple of variants, or look up the exact spelling in the directory listings of `/usr/share/themes` and `/usr/share/icons`.

Comment: great!!! Woks perfect!